# Is there a way to initialize a counter based on condition in Hive/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in which I need to tag number of different transactions for each group. If the number of days between 2 subsequent transactions is less than 7 then it would be considered as a same transaction, otherwise a different transaction.

The tx_data table I have looks like:

```
User    tx_Dt
A       1/10/2018
A       1/10/2018
A       1/10/2018
A       1/11/2019
A       1/11/2019
A       1/11/2019
A       1/12/2019
A       1/12/2019
D       1/29/2019
D       2/4/2019
D       2/5/2019
E       12/14/2019
E       12/14/2019
E       12/16/2019
E       12/28/2019
```

The desired output is:

```
User    tx_Dt       tx_tag  
A       1/10/2018   1
A       1/10/2018   1
A       1/10/2018   1
A       1/11/2019   2
A       1/11/2019   2
A       1/11/2019   2
A       1/12/2019   2
A       1/12/2019   2
D       1/29/2019   1
D       2/4/2019    1
D       2/5/2019    1
E       12/14/2019  1
E       12/14/2019  1
E       12/16/2019  1
E       12/28/2019  2
```

I've tried multiple things like case when, sum() over(partition by order by), inner joins but have not been able to initiate a counter which re-initializes at each group by level.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` and cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_tx_dt > date_add(tx_dt, -7) then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by user order by tx_dt) as tx_tag
from (select t.*,
             lag(tx_Dt) over (partition by user order by tx_Dt) as prev_tx_dt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: This gives me the following output:
`t.user t.tx_dt  t.prev_tx_dt tx_tag`
`A  1/10/2018     3`
`A  1/10/2018 1/10/2018  3`
`A  1/10/2018 1/10/2018  3`
`A  1/11/2019 1/11/2019  6`
`A  1/11/2019 1/11/2019  6`
`A  1/11/2019 1/10/2018  6`
`A  1/12/2019 1/11/2019  8`
`A  1/12/2019 1/12/2019  8`
`D  1/29/2019     1`
`D  2/4/2019 1/29/2019  2`
`D  2/5/2019 2/4/2019  3`
`E  12/14/2019 12/14/2019  2`
`E  12/14/2019     2`
`E  12/16/2019 12/14/2019  3`
`E  12/28/2019 12/16/2019  4`